# pseudo-streaming of wmv files

Tags: video, streaming, wmv

Is it possible to do pseudo-streaming(eg start playback at any point) with wmv files and silverlight?

This is possible using Flash in a progressive download setup but can it be done on the Microsoft track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question, Microsoft has released [Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/extensions/SmoothStreaming), which is exactly what I was asking for and more.

Clearly this is the best Silverlight solution although you do need Windows Server 2008 on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can **use [Windows Media Services 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/version.aspx)**. It enables you to actually stream WMV to Silverlight interface.

Comment: I know that works but I am looking for a progressive download solution.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only simple solution at the moment. And it's free if you have WInServer license.

Answer (score 0):

No reason you couldn't stream it like any other HTTP video; it basically just expects the file to be a correct WMV file. You would need to have a server that supports the seeking, though.